# How do I get both objects and values() from a single Django query?

Tags: database, django, django-models, atomic, transaction-isolation

I want to export some database objects as JSON.  The export format more or less matches the format of `Example.objects.values(*columns)`, except each dict should also contain a value computed by calling a method on each of `Example.objects.all()`, that is, on the `class Example(Model)` instances.

How do I produce a suitable dictionary with **only one** database query?

My motivation for collapsing two queries (my current solution) into one is consistency: we run Django against PostgreSQL at the default "read committed" level, which may make my two queries return inconsistent data.  (The better performance is a benefit too, but not the main motivation.)

I see two paths:

1. query for objects and convert the objects to dictionaries in my python code.
2. query for dictionaries and convert the dictionaries to objects in my  python code.

Which is better?  What should I watch out for?  How do I do either one correctly?  Django does a lot of complex stuff behind the scenes—the code I looked at seemed somewhat complex, anyways—so I'm not sure: which path is the most robust?

**NOTE**: the solution needs to span `__` lookups, i.e. I want to have e.g. `{"other_model__pk": 1}` be a possible output.  A quick tests suggests that `django.forms.models.model_to_dict` doesn't do this.

Comment: Is using SQL to get this straight from the database out of the question?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that addresses the question.  How do I turn an SQL response into `class Example(Model)` instances?  How do I turn the data into a list of dictionaries?  It seems to be more work than starting with one and computing the other.  You could be right, of course, but for me to see that, I'd need to have your idea elaborated a bit.

Comment: I'm maybe not understanding the question. As I see it your ultimate goal is to produce some JSON including both the values in > 1 database table and, additionally, a calculated value. I would approach this by writing a query that drew the data you needed with appropriate `JOIN`s and adding a column in pure SQL that replicated whatever calculation your model method is doing. I believe you can even output directly as JSON using [PostgreSQL's JSON support](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql)

Comment: Ah, so your answer is essentially "do the method in SQL instead of in python".  I think that'll be my long term solution; it's a bit of work, though, so until that's done it would be nice to have a way to avoid the double queries.